# Chrome calls timeouts before their time in particular timings window focus loss

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout

Here is some code that runs a function every second using `setTimeout` and then checks that the function wasn't called too early.

```
var date = Date.now(); 
var ttl=1000, 
    to = setTimeout(function loop () {
       console.log("triggered!"); 
       if (Date.now() - date < ttl) 
         console.error("Yes"); 
       date = Date.now(); 
       to = setTimeout(loop, ttl);
     }, ttl);
```

The `console.error` call should never occur. But if you are on chrome and hit `Alt+Tab` fast enough and enough times it will sometimes appear. I know chrome does some weird stuff with timeouts <1s when a tab looses focus but AFAIK it timeouts are only prolonged, never shortened.

EDIT: While I was writing this post I left such a loop running. When I went back at it here is what I see:

[image: Premature timeouts]

Comment: I guess it have something todo how Javascript handles timeouts and intervals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful You should check how much it is too early and than maybe add some "valid range" (about +/- 5ms) to your checks.

Comment: While +10ms is acceptable, -10ms is not. The way I [understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes) the js scheduler will wait at **least** `timeout` ms before executing the code. Never less.

Comment: So maybe there is not a bug with the javascript interval but instead with Date.now() accuracy? Try this http://www.sitepoint.com/discovering-the-high-resolution-time-api/